# Server cleanup after a client disconnects

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there a way to detect when a client disconnects from a meteor server, either by refreshing or navigating away from the page, so that the server can attempt some cleanup?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One technique is to implement a "keepalive" method that each client regularly calls.  This assumes you've got a `user_id` held in each client's `Session`.

```
// server code: heartbeat method
Meteor.methods({
  keepalive: function (user_id) {
    if (!Connections.findOne(user_id))
      Connections.insert({user_id: user_id});

    Connections.update(user_id, {$set: {last_seen: (new Date()).getTime()}});
  }
});

// server code: clean up dead clients after 60 seconds
Meteor.setInterval(function () {
  var now = (new Date()).getTime();
  Connections.find({last_seen: {$lt: (now - 60 * 1000)}}).forEach(function (user) {
    // do something here for each idle user
  });
});

// client code: ping heartbeat every 5 seconds
Meteor.setInterval(function () {
  Meteor.call('keepalive', Session.get('user_id'));
}, 5000);
```

Comment: After much searching i think this is the best solution for now. Thanks!!

Comment: This is almost pseudocode, as in it's not functional as is: the first setInterval has no interval specified. Also the Connections.update command doesn't specify to update {'user_id':user_id}. There may be other errors. It's a fine start though.

Comment: @debergalis Is this still the recommended way to see if clients are dead?

Comment: @debergalis I'd like to know if you'd still recommend this method

Answer (score 13):

I think better way is to catch socket close event in publish function.

```
Meteor.publish("your_collection", function() {
    this.session.socket.on("close", function() { /*do your thing*/});
}
```

UPDATE:

Newer version of meteor uses _session like this:

```
this._session.socket.on("close", function() { /*do your thing*/});
```

Comment: That's great.  But then I apparently run into this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192938/meteor-code-must-always-run-within-a-fiber-when-calling-collection-insert-on-s

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer to my question: [Meteor observe running forever](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12902392/599991)

Comment: I use meteor 0.6.1 and for this line `this.session.socket.on("close", function() { /*do your thing*/});` my server returns _TypeError: Cannot read property 'socket' of undefined_ But when I correct it to `this._session.socket.on("close", function() { /*do your thing*/});` it works great, thanks

Comment: In 0.6.3.1 it's not 100% reliable, sadly.

Comment: How come the Meteor docs doesn't say anything about this or sockets? I couldn't find any mention of _session variable or sockets?

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a Meteor smart package that tracks all connected sessions from different sessions and detects both session logout and disconnect events, without an expensive keepalive.

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status

To detect disconnect/logout events, you can just do the following:

```
UserStatus.on "connectionLogout", (info) ->
  console.log(info.userId + " with session " + info.connectionId + " logged out")
```

You can also use it reactively. Check it out!

**EDIT:** `v0.3.0` of user-status now tracks users being idle as well!

Comment: Can this be done on a per page basis and not through the entire app?

Comment: Yes, although that isn't implemented yet. Open a feature request!

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Auth you have access to the user's ID in Method and Publish functions, you could implement your tracking there.. e.g. you could set a "last seen" when the user switches room:

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function(roomId) {
    // assuming ActiveConnections is where you're tracking user connection activity
    ActiveConnections.update({ userId: this.userId() }, {
        $set:{ lastSeen: new Date().getTime() }
    });
    return Messages.find({ roomId: roomId});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using [Iron Router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router) and call my cleanup code on the `unload` event of my main controller. Sure this will not catch the event of a tab closing, but still feels good enough for many use cases

```
ApplicationController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: 'root',
    data: {},
    fastRender: true,
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        this.next();
    },
    unload: function () {
        if(Meteor.userId())
            Meteor.call('CleanUpTheUsersTrash');
    },
    action: function () {
        console.log('this should be overridden by our actual controllers!');
    }
});
```