# Meteor client disconnected event on server

Tags: javascript, meteor

Simple question, maybe simple answer: how do I know on the server that a certain client has disconnected? Basic use case: the serve would need to know if a player has dropped the connection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257958/server-cleanup-after-a-client-disconnects

Comment: just added an alternative way of tracking user connection status on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257958/server-cleanup-after-a-client-disconnects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do one thing make a event on server and call it from browser **with ajax** which call **after some small time interval settimeinterval** using with session values into header and if server din`t get request from user it means he dropped connection

Comment: try it and let me know if you stuck somewhere

Answer (score 4):

In the publish function, you can watch socket close event as follows.

```
this.session.socket.on "close", -> # do your thing
```

Comment: The correct name for the session variable is `_session`.

Answer (score 4):

```
 Meteor.publish("yourPublishFunction", function()
        {
            var id = this._session.userId;
            this._session.socket.on("close", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function()
            {
              console.log(id); // called once the user disconnects
            }, function(e){console.log(e)}));

            return YourCollection.find({});
        });
```

Comment: Why did you use `Meteor.bindEnvironment`?

Comment: … probably useless in most of the cases, I can imagine I was using it in my original code and just forgot to remove it for the SO post.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a pretty comprehensive package to keep track of all logged-in sessions from every user, as well as their IP addresses and activity:

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status

To watch for disconnects, you can just do the following, which catches both logouts and browser closes:

```
UserStatus.on "sessionLogout", (userId, sessionId) ->
  console.log(userId + " with session " + sessionId + " logged out")
```

You can also check out the code and do something similar for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (in the server code)

```
Meteor.default_server.sessions.length
```

or

```
Meteor.default_server.stream_server.open_sockets.length
```