# Meteor observe running forever

Tags: meteor

According to [observe docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe), I must define and call a *stop* function, or my observer **will run forever**. The point, is how to call *stop* if the user decided to close his browser before the expected time, for example? How can I call *stop* if a conection is dead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need to worry about disconnects.  Any time the subscription stops (whether the client disconnects, or calls unsub, or you call `this.stop`), the server will run all the registered `onStop` handlers before tearing down the active subscription.  (Teardown doesn't happen immediately on disconnect, by the way, but it will eventually.  The idea is to wait a bit, in case the client tries to reconnect and resume its session.)

What you **do** need to do is make sure to register an `onStop` handler that cleans up any resources your code used.  Again, that needs to happen anytime the subscription is stopped.  `onStop` is the right hook.  It's critically important to call `stop` on an active observe, for example, just like in the first code stanza in the example.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you can call it inside your publish:

```
this.session.socket.on("close", function() { /*do your thing*/});
```

So, if you wanna stop an observer...

```
Meteor.publish("something", function () {

  // ...
  // your observers code here
  // ...

  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
  this.session.socket.on("close", function() {
    handle.stop();
  });
});
```

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12505615/599991). Thanks goes to Zhou Huabing.