# How to track the number of anonymous users server-side in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm writing a data-sensitive application in Meteor, and am trying to limit the client access to as much information as possible. Therefore, I want to implement server side a way of counting the number of logged-in, and anonymous, users.

I have tried a variety of methods. The first was as outlined in this question [Server cleanup after a client disconnects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257958/server-cleanup-after-a-client-disconnects), which suggests hooking into:

```
this.session.socket.on("close")
```

However when I did, and tried to change a collection, it threw a "Meteor code must always run within a Fiber" error. I assume this problem is because once the socket is closed, that Fiber is killed, and so accessing the database is impossible. The OP pointed to this ["Meteor code must always run within a Fiber" when calling Collection.insert on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192938/meteor-code-must-always-run-within-a-fiber-when-calling-collection-insert-on-s) as a possible solution, but I wasn't sure if that's the best method, based on the comments to the answer.

I then tried to autorun on the variable:

```
Meteor.default_server.stream_server.all_sockets().length
```

but the autorun never seemed to be called, so I'm assuming that variable is not a reactive context, and I wasn't sure how to make it one.

The last idea was to do a keepalive style thing, but that seems to completely go against the grain of the Meteor philosophy, and I think I'll only use as an absolute last resort.

I did a `console.log` of the functions on `this.session.socket`, and the only other function possible was `.on("data")`, but this isn't called when the socket is closed.

I'm at a bit of a loss here, so any help would be great,
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, it's probably best to combine the two answers above. In other words, do the following:

- Keep the online status in `Meteor.users`, as opposed to a separate collection, as in https://github.com/erundook/meteor-profile-online
- Keep track of disconnections via callback, instead of a heartbeat, as in https://github.com/murilopolese/howmanypeoplearelooking

This would probably be the canonical way to implement this in Meteor. I've created this as a smart package that you can install with Meteorite: https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status

Comment: Whilst this is very cool, the docs specifically say it doesn't track anon users so it doesn't really answer the original question.

Comment: @cazgp Since I wrote this post, I've updated the package to track anonymous users. Obviously we cannot track anonymous users in `Meteor.users`, but their connections are all tracked.

Comment: Just needed to do this myself. With @AndrewMao's `mizzao:meteor-user-status` package getting the anonymous user count is as easy as querying the in-memory `UserStatus.connections` collection for connections without a `userId`... `UserStatus.connections.find({userId: {$exists: false}}).count()`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Sorhus' tip, I managed to solve this. His answer contains a heartbeat, which I was keen to avoid. However, it contained the trick of using Meteor's "bindEnvironment". This allows access to a collection, which otherwise would not be accessible.

```
Meteor.publish("whatever", function() {
  userId = this.userId;
  if(userId) Stats.update({}, {$addToSet: {users: userId}});
  else Stats.update({}, {$inc: {users_anon: 1}});

  // This is required, because otherwise each time the publish function is called,
  // the events re-bind and the counts will start becoming ridiculous as the functions
  // are called multiple times!
  if(this.session.socket._events.data.length === 1) {

    this.session.socket.on("data", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(data) {
      var method = JSON.parse(data).method;

      // If a user is logging in, dec anon. Don't need to add user to set,
      // because when a user logs in, they are re-subscribed to the collection,
      // so the publish function will be called again.
      // Similarly, if they logout, they re-subscribe, and so the anon count
      // will be handled when the publish function is called again - need only
      // to take out the user ID from the users array.
      if(method === 'login')
        Stats.update({}, {$inc: {users_anon: -1}});

      // If a user is logging out, remove from set
      else if(method === 'logout')
        Stats.update({}, {$pull: {users: userId}});

    }, function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }));

    this.session.socket.on("close", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
      if(userId === null || userId === undefined) 
        Stats.update({}, {$inc: {users_anon: -1}});
      else
        Stats.update({}, {$pull: {users: userId}});
    }, function(e) {
      console.log("close error", e);
    }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the GitHub project [howmanypeoplearelooking](https://github.com/murilopolese/howmanypeoplearelooking)

> Meteor application test to show how many users are online right now.

Comment: It's a prank. I've downloaded the code (`Dumbs = new Meteor.Collection("dumbs");` :) )

Comment: @Matanya: `Dumbs` is just a childish collection name, but [the app works](https://github.com/murilopolese/howmanypeoplearelooking/pull/2).