# Meteor insert / remove operations raise exception when called from ZeroMQ callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, zeromq

The following Meteor code snippet barfs when a ZeroMQ message is received on the specified port.  However, if I change `remove` to `find`, it works OK.  `insert` operations also fail.  Note that `insert` and `remove` succeed if run outside of the callbacks, e.g. just below the `pull.on` part.

```
var Components = new Meteor.Collection("components");

function handle_message(msg) {
    console.log("pull on message" + msg);
    Components.remove();
}


if (Meteor.isServer) {
     Meteor.startup(function () {
        var zmq = Meteor.require("zmq");
        var pull = zmq.socket("pull");
        pull.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:7000", function(data) {
           console.log("Connection received from ZMQ");
        });
        pull.on('message', handle_message);

    });
}
```

Exception is:

```
W20130827-21:36:21.800(0)? (STDERR) packages/mongo-livedata.js:1640
W20130827-21:36:21.802(0)? (STDERR)         throw e;                                                              
W20130827-21:36:21.803(0)? (STDERR)               ^
W20130827-21:36:21.843(0)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot read property '_meteor_dynamics' of undefined
W20130827-21:36:21.843(0)? (STDERR)     at Object.Meteor.bindEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:55)
W20130827-21:36:21.845(0)? (STDERR)     at _.extend._wrapAsync (packages/meteor/helpers.js:108)
W20130827-21:36:21.845(0)? (STDERR)     at _.each.MongoConnection.(anonymous function) [as remove] (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:340)
W20130827-21:36:21.846(0)? (STDERR)     at _.each.Meteor.Collection.(anonymous function) [as remove] (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:406)
W20130827-21:36:21.846(0)? (STDERR)     at Socket.handle_message (app/web.js:5:16)
W20130827-21:36:21.847(0)? (STDERR)     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
W20130827-21:36:21.847(0)? (STDERR)     at Socket._flush._flushing (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/ad83acff83385d5ea05997c8bbc2d7493ba4c04e/.build/npm/node_modules/zmq/lib/index.js:358:25)
W20130827-21:36:21.852(0)? (STDERR)     at global.setImmediate (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/ad83acff83385d5ea05997c8bbc2d7493ba4c04e/.build/npm/node_modules/zmq/node_modules/set-immediate/setImmediate.js:15:9)
W20130827-21:36:21.852(0)? (STDERR)     at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:245:9)
```

Any one have any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544333/how-to-track-the-number-of-anonymous-users-server-side-in-meteor) which solved the problem (though I don't claim to fully understand it yet).  Wrapping the callback in `Meteor.bindEnvironment` eliminates the error and handles `remove` and `insert` correctly.  As a Meteor newb, I will happily accept another answer which provides a good explanation for why / how this works.

```
var Components = new Meteor.Collection("components");

function handle_message(msg) {
    console.log("pull on message" + msg);
    Components.insert({"name": "foo", "state": "stopped"});
}

bound_handle_message = Meteor.bindEnvironment(handle_message, function(e) {
    console.log("exception! " + e); 
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
     Meteor.startup(function () {
        var zmq = Meteor.require("zmq");
        var pull = zmq.socket("pull");
        pull.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:7000", function(data) {
           console.log("Connection received from ZMQ");
        });
        pull.on('message', bound_handle_message);

    });
}
```