# meteor - get all subscriber session handles for a publisher method

Tags: meteor

I want to broadcast NON-MONGO-DB data from a server publisher to client collections. Currently I save all registered subscriber handles to use those for posting the data

```
client.js:

col = new Meteor.Collection("data")

Meteor.subscribe("stream")
```

On server side it looks like

```
server.js

all_handles = [];

Meteor.publish("stream", function() {
  // safe reference to this sessions
  var self = this;
  // save reference to this subscriber
  all_handles.push(self);
  // signal ready
  self.ready();
  // on stop subscription remove this handle from list
  self.onStop(function() {
    all_handles = _.without(all_handles, self); 
  }
}
```

Then I can use the all_handles somewhere in my app to send data to those clients, like:

```
function broadcast(msg) {
  all_handles.forEach(function(handle) {
    handle.added("data", Random.id(), msg);
  }
}
```

This is already in use and running.

Q: What I am looking for is: Can I get all handles from currently already existing meteor (internal) objects like _sessions or something else?

It would be great if I had not to organize the subscribers handle all the time by myself.

Please do not answer with links to other broadcast packages like streamy or else. I want to continue with standard collections but with as less code as possible.

Thanks for help and feedback
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As informed by @laberning I used for now the "undocumented" meteor connections.

You can post to all subscribers of a publishing method like:

```
// publish updated values to all subscribers
function publish_to_all_subscribers(subscription_name, id, data) {
  _.each(Meteor.server.stream_server.open_sockets, function(connection) {
    _.each(connection._meteorSession._namedSubs, function(sub) {
      if (sub._name == subscription_name) {
        sub.insert(subscription_name, id, data);
      }
    })
  });
}

// create stream publisher
Meteor.publish('stream', function(){
  // set ready
  this.ready();
});

...
// use publishing somewhere in your app
publish_to_all_subscribers('stream', Random.id(), {msg: "Hello to all"});
...
```

---

updated: See an example [MeteorPad for Publish and Subscribe and Broadcast messages](http://meteorpad.com/pad/3PvtrYTKLLemDyK2x/Streaming%20and%20Publishing%20to%20all)

Comment: If some knows an official Meteor property for that, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30814101/2005564

You could get the connections via `var connections = Meteor.server.stream_server.open_sockets;` but as looshi said this might break with a future meteor update as it is not part of the public API...

Comment: Thanks for your post. I am wondering if there isn't a solid MDG solution for that simple requirement.