# Meteor and client to client communication in between different servers on the same db

Tags: meteor, ddp

I've split my project into smaller microservices sharing the same db but running on different server instances. I'm trying to communicate messages from client side at server A to clients on server B. The project structure looks like the following:

```
/admin
  symlink packages
  .meteor
/web
  symlink packages
  .meteor
/cordova
  symlink packages
  .meteor
/packages
```

A practical example would be to notify all connected clients of a new post, without saving a new post event to the db. In my case, it is not important to store such information, but just to display them to clients currently connected.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you tried communicating between servers with DDP?

Comment: I've tried to connect them and used a technique outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180799/meteor-get-all-subscriber-session-handles-for-a-publisher-method), [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/3PvtrYTKLLemDyK2x/Streaming%20and%20Publishing%20to%20all) but with no success.

I think the problem is currently, that each Meteor.method call is fired on the same server instance, but not a the others. A solution would probably be to call the method on a servers at the same time - any ideas how to do that?