# Meteor, get all users on a specific page

Tags: meteor, user-presence

We are building a chat application and are currently working on a system to see all the users in a given room.

We have a Mongo Document set up with an array of `active_users` where we will `push` and `pull` user names to in order to keep track of the online users. We have come to the conclusion that realizing a user has connected to a given room is fairly simple. All we need to do is in the router, when a user accesses the page, we `push` that user's name into the document.

Now the tricky part is realizing when that user has left that given page? Obviously jQuery isn't a reliable option, so how do we know when a user's connection to a specific page is broken?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server cleanup after a client disconnects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257958/server-cleanup-after-a-client-disconnects)

Comment: The [chatroom code for CrowdMapper](https://github.com/mizzao/CrowdMapper/blob/master/server/chat_server.coffee) is basically doing most of what you're asking for already.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Meteor.publish("page", function() {
    this._session.socket.on("close", function() { 
        //Change your active users here
    });
});
```

and for your page that you track

```
Meteor.subscribe('page');
```

I use this in the `analytics` package on atmosphere

Answer (score 0):

There's an Atmosphere package called [Presence](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-presence) that does exactly what you need.

Some extra details from the README about keeping track of custom states...

#### State functions

If you want to track more than just users' online state, you can set a custom state function. (The default state function returns just `'online'`):

```
// Setup the state function on the client
Presence.state = function() {
  return {
    online: true,
    currentRoomId: Session.get('currentRoomId')
  };
}
```

Now we can simply query the collection to find all other users that share the same currentRoomId

```
Presences.find({ state: { online: true, currentRoomId: Session.get('currentRoomId') } })
```

Of course, presence will call your function reactively, so everyone will know as soon as things change.

Comment: Would this work for if I wanted to store a set of rooms that a the user is currently in? I.e. A user is in 5 rooms at the same time, and I want to know all of the rooms they are in.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor has [connection hooks](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_onconnection) so you can run a function when the user disconnects from the server.  Setting the onClose() callback inside a method called by the client will allow you to close the userId in the function.

Code on the server could be like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  joinRoom: function( roomId ){
    var self = this;
    Rooms.update( {roomId: roomId}, {$push:{userId: self.userId}});

    self.connection.onClose( function(){
      Rooms.update( {roomId: roomId}, {$pull:{userId: self.userId}})
    });    
  }
});
```

Comment: I dont think this is going to work because this will only handle if the user is online, not exactly which rooms the user is actively in.

Comment: Aren't you able to call a method ( maybe from the router ) each time a user changes or leaves a room?  If you can maintain the list of rooms they are in while active then also maintain an onClose() function to remove them when they go offline.  I didn't mean to write a complete solution just a basic example of the functionality.