# Can I use meteor for this?

Tags: socket.io, meteor

I'm looking for a way to create an app which has a realtime web interface as well as an API which can be called by a node.js client while sharing most of its code.

I'd like to be able to manage data, monitor and execute tasks inside of my app via browser, but also have an automation/scheduling program which connects to my web app and tells it to run various tasks and get results of each task.

Unfortunately it doesn't look like I can connect to Meteor from the server, so I'm wondering if there's another approach?  Is what I described even possible using Meteor?

I have done some testing using socket.io and I think I may be able to do it this way, but Meteor seems like it'd be really great for the realtime user interface.

Comment: _"Unfortunately it doesn't look like I can connect to Meteor from the server, so I'm wondering if there's another approach?"_ Please refrase your question as you are not very precise in what you want to have.

Comment: So do you mean something like remote functions or publish/subsribe? Or something different? (The first two items are supported by Meteor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you [can use npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165978/how-do-we-or-can-we-use-node-modules-via-npm-with-meteor) to do what you want. Just like standard Node.js programming.

There might be one error you run into when calling Meteor between external code, but it is [easy to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192938/meteor-code-must-always-run-within-a-fiber-when-calling-collection-insert-on-s).

I guess in your case you could set up a TCP server that way and make it update a collection, then you could get the clients to update through the reactive collection publishing mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, I realized you could use outside packages but your mention of a TCP server to update a collection was helpful.  I'm going to develop my "backend" using hook.io, and Meteor will be another hook listening for events to update collections.  Hopefully it works out!