# How to insert in Collection within a Fiber?

Tags: meteor

I want to insert in the Tweets collection every tweets from the stream made with Twit (npm module), inside a method.

### Here is my code:

```
stream: function(hashtag) {
    //Création du stream
    stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: hashtag });
    var currentHashtag = hashtag;

    // Lance le stream
    stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
         var userName = tweet.user.screen_name;
            var userTweet = tweet.text;
            var tweetDate = tweet.created_at;
            var profileImg = tweet.user.profile_image_url;

        console.log(userName+" a tweeté: "+userTweet+" le: "+tweetDate);
        console.log("=======================");

        Tweets.insert({user: userName, tweet: userTweet, picture: profileImg, date: tweetDate, hashtag: currentHashtag}, function(error) {
            if(error)
                console.log(error);
        });
    });
}
```

And here is my error message:
[Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor Libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment. ]

I've tried different solutions in vain, like wrap the Collection insertion in a Fiber(), and I try to use a Meteor.bindEnvironment, but never understand how to properly use it.

Can you help me ?

===================================================

### Edit:

I've tried this. With this code, I don't have any errors anymore, but the tweets aren't inserted in my Collection.

```
    stream.on('tweet', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(tweet) {
       var tweetToInsert = {
            user: tweet.user.screen_name, 
            tweet: tweet.text, 
            picture: tweet.user.profile_image_url, 
            date: tweet.created_at, 
            hashtag: currentHashtag
        };

        console.log(tweetToInsert.user+" a tweeté: "+tweetToInsert.tweet+" le: "+tweetToInsert.date+" \n "+tweetToInsert.picture+"\n"+tweetToInsert.hashtag);
        console.log("=======================");

        Tweets.insert(tweetToInsert, function(error, result) {
            if(error)
                console.log(error);
            else
                console.log(result);
        });
    }));
```

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192938/meteor-code-must-always-run-within-a-fiber-when-calling-collection-insert-on-s/18541825#18541825

Comment: Yes, but the context is different, and I don't understand your solution, can you explain more ?

Comment: wrap your callbacks from stream.on into Meteor.bindEnvironment

Comment: I made it, but the Tweets.insert don't work, any idea ?

Answer (score 5):

You can run a Fiber on insert:

```
var Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
Fiber(function () {
   Tweets.insert({user: userName, tweet: userTweet, picture: profileImg, date: tweetDate, hashtag: currentHashtag}, function(error) {
      if(error)
         console.log(error);
    });
}).run();
```

Comment: I don't have any errors displayed anymore, but it doesn't work. My collection remains empty !

Comment: I've known this as `new Fiber().run()`, not sure if this makes a difference though.