# Getting currentUser id from server

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to update a the user "photoPath" field after uploading a file using [meteor-uploads](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads). 
I'm getting this error :

> Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping
>   callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with
>   Meteor.bindEnvironment.

server/init.js

```
validateFile: function(file, req) {
    Meteor.users.update( { _id: Meteor.userId() }, {$set: {"profile.photoPath": req.path}});

    return null; 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Meteor code must always run within a Fiber" when calling Collection.insert on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192938/meteor-code-must-always-run-within-a-fiber-when-calling-collection-insert-on-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use
  **this.userId**
to access user from server side